# How can I take all the elements / fields from a Listbox (in C#) and put them into a DataTable?

Tags: c#, datatable, listbox

I have a win form which has a `ListBox`. I want to create dynamically a `DataTable` (till now I only declared some columns - you can see in the code - that I later want to use to link the `DataTable` to an existing empty `DataBase`) but don't know how to link it to the `Listbox` in order to "take" the 4 elements from it: `event_time , event_filename , event_name , event_fullpath`. Pls Help,

Part of my code till now is:

```
    private delegate void AppendListHandler(string event_filename, String event_name, String event_fullpath);

    private void AppendText(string event_filename, String event_name, String event_fullpath)
    {
        if (lstResultLog.InvokeRequired)
            lstResultLog.Invoke(new AppendListHandler(AppendText), new object[] { event_filename, event_name, event_fullpath });
        else
        {
            DateTime event_time = DateTime.Now;
            //String event_duration = event_time.ToString("HH:mm");
            lstResultLog.Items.Add(event_time + event_filename + event_name + event_fullpath);
        }

        DataTable table = new DataTable("tbl_Event");
        table.Columns.Add("event_duration");
        table.Columns.Add("event_name");
        table.Columns.Add("event_filename");
        table.Columns.Add("event_fullpath");
        table = (DataTable)lstResultLog.DataSource;
    }
```

`lstResultLog` is the name of the ListBox, all the fields from the ListBox have the exact name as in the declared DataTable, and as the DataBase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have in your form a field of type `DataTable` that will hold the data you want. Then, whenever you add an item to your listbox, add a row to the data table with same data:

```
public class YourForm
{
    private DataTable _table;
    public YourForm()
    {
        InitializeComponents();
        _table = BuildDataTable();
    }

    private DataTable BuildDataTable()
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable("tbl_Event");
        table.Columns.Add("event_duration");
        table.Columns.Add("event_name");
        table.Columns.Add("event_filename");
        table.Columns.Add("event_fullpath");
        return table;
    }

    private void AppendText(string event_filename, String event_name, String event_fullpath)
    {
        if (lstResultLog.InvokeRequired)
            lstResultLog.Invoke(new AppendListHandler(AppendText), new object[] { event_filename, event_name, event_fullpath });
        else
        {
            DateTime event_time = DateTime.Now;
            lstResultLog.Items.Add(event_time + event_filename + event_name + event_fullpath);
            //Create new row
            var row = _table.NewRow();
            // Fill row values
            row["event_name"] = event_name;
            // Add row to table
            _table.Rows.Add(row);
        }
    }
}
```

And when you need to send the data to database, just send `_table` field as a parameter to the method that saves data.

Comment: hello, Its a great idea! if you don't mind I would also like to ask this: I quite don't know how to:

Comment: @MPN, what is the question?

Comment: hello, Its a great idea! if you don't mind I would also like to ask this: I quite don't have ideas (but Im working on it - google+books) on how for to:1. separate the items from the ListBox (`lstResultLog`) then 2. insert them in the first row of the `DataTable` (`_table`) (shouldn't I be needing a `foreach` because I guess you can't give a name for each row) 3. with what method should I pass the (`_table`) to the DB? thx in advance, and sorry for my un-knowledge :) @RePierre

Comment: @MPN, Each time you call `ApendText` method you add a new item in `lstResultLog` and a new row in `_table` field. This means that for each line in the listbox you'll have a table row with data separated in columns. As for 3. I suggest creating a class (let's say `DataStore`) and within that class you'll have a method (let's say `internal static void SaveEvents(DataTable table)`. Then, in your form you'd just call the method like this `DataStore.SaveEvents(_table);`.

Comment: thx again for the great help!!! I kinda got it with the rows after I posted. I don't know yet if the rows saved into the _table, but want to make the procedure for the DB, then I will know from the database, and then I shall thank you again!!!

Comment: works great!!! thank for saving a lot of hours/days maybe, and learned somethink also!